# How to order pages in redirect page selection

Tags: aem

We have thousands of pages in our CQ repository and the repository is not (or doesn't appear to be) ordered. When we're creating redirect pages the page selection dialog is not ordered and it makes it extremely difficult to find the page we're interested in. Is there some way to tell CQ to order the results in the built-in components?

Comment: what do you mean by ordered ? ordered by modified or created or something else ?

Comment: We'd like them to be ordered alpha by node name. This may not be possible as the dialog in question is displaying the JCR repository in tree form. We may have to investigate creating our own dialog that could be used to select the redirect pages.